# python bitwise operation

Tags: python

hi i am new in python just started learning with python i got a task in which i need to store "1" byte of integer into different bits just like RGB the value are store in that can any one would write a small program for me and explain that ,please i need a help

Thankyou

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is this homework?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by making sure you understand what these operators do:  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bit-string-operations-on-integer-types

Comment: `can any one would write a small program for me` no

Comment: Its not a homework its a task and need to understand and explain to other

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's homework or not. We're not here to write code for you

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume this question is legitimate and appropriate for the forum..

```
# To Encode:
r = 1
g = 2
b = 3

rgb = r << 16 | g << 8 | b

#To extract:
r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF
g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF
b = rgb & 0xFF
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a number to a list of it's binary digits: `list(bin(number))[2:]`